# select from one table to another table in jdbc

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

How to execute SQL Server query into JDBC like this SQL?

```
select * into bk_table from existing_table
```

**Expected**:   Above query should be executed through JDBC.
**Actual**: Query is not working through JDBC in any way.I tried following two ways but nothing happens or affected in DBMS.

```
    String sql="select * into bk_table from existing_table";
    //tried way 1-> result: false
    statement.execute(sql);
    //tried way 2-> result: -1
    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

What to do now?

Comment: What would you like to do? Select mean retrieve record from table. Syntax : Select * from Table, not into.

Comment: The problem is with your sql query, not the JDBC. What exactly do you want to achieve ? Cause as Myo said before me, Select means you want to get some records, so please explain what do you want to do. 
Cheers !

Comment: Query is working fine by executing on  SQL server but i want to execute this through JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an insert-select statement. It can be called with `executeUpdate`:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO bk_table SELECT * FROM existing_table";
statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: I mentioned above in question that i tried it. This way gives -1 in result and do nothing

Comment: @islamuddin no, you tried `executeUpdate` with the wrong sql (`select.. into..`) instead of the one I suggested.

Comment: yeah, got it. Sorry,I missed attention to detail. Thanks for attention.I tried this way but this is not my expected way because your above statement suggest to create bk_table first.

Answer (score 0):

To select data from old table, "SELECT * FROM bk_table";

To insert the selected data from old to existing table, "INSERT INTO existing_table SELECT * FROM bk_table";

Comment: please read my question. Your answer refer to SQL queries. I have not problem with SQL queries but cocerned on running these queries on jdbc.